# PHP Google translate service v3 - connection problem - guzzlehttp

Tags: php, connection, google-translate

The code in PHP:

```
<?php

require 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\vendor\autoload.php';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\secret\central-eon-267809-2d6dc3c388dc.json');
use Google\Cloud\Translate\V3\TranslationServiceClient;

function translate($text, $to){

$projectId = "central-eon-267809";
$translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
$string = $text;
$string = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($string));
$string = utf8_encode($string);
$content = [$string];
$targetLanguage = $to;
$response = $translationClient->translateText(
    $content,
    $targetLanguage,
    TranslationServiceClient::locationName($projectId, 'global')
);

foreach ($response->getTranslations() as $key => $translation) {
    $separator = $key === 2
        ? '!'
        : ', ';
    return $translation->getTranslatedText(); //. $separator;
}
}
?>
```

The Json-file (i'll make a new one when solved):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "central-eon-267809",
  "private_key_id": "2d6dc3c388dc908c8fc440d238f0a9d237d0c2b9",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDPdczc7pvqh14I\nFJee/Ayhygn80nK6dKe8v6JZeMgfUx7e5/ziaV7oDufw/FAtkfRXa6YE7IMnmLeZ\nQ5hv3/PDEZ/Gs4QvBlaIGVAcN2Omi3k3eeC/osc1RzoVm7uG+eW9rjUe/XqtfVfV\nHhpnt5UbRR0uB0m4t/sIikprmS7gSL8ft80M7fYc2f7c9sQgkUlgwbYIogXVbxhl\n1Vym61PikgYnbAksZsHKEvRDdQx/+lzfvggMMeKlxw88DpFTIVyxctz/MkrY4Jid\n67Hj9L4A1Kcw981nDGGEefQ7yj3M2H9MLq6bGZs78Qv/dUi3nwcQaoHxKI592zrd\nfMFb9MLrAgMBAAECggEAILg2CsQ75VCF5Tqw3RtojJ3LrHWuhYy/exaIRESMijA3\nBrX08uqRKYKsVHF0Mx5kDeOa/VzQpKPtP6gNuIX22+sBgDpbhyUglvooYdg0iGr9\nP7bNBRG8Xxaa6Rc04NQJ8WaygcQ9nx4ihlNnRmNfChGA9CZPG2nc7EW5+LVh/hpX\nhf65wSimaw9Rz97r+9+8G0ByjJyRiV9xTQGdgBh6Kfn19Pt4DWAQAcbI2OiLIIw4\n+ppdATN6oZAd8Bz3REInkpKSlFycFYSqj2Jx3wQWcEjxRxXg2jftxQWeeK9FZS57\n14ZfaB0E2w8yHHEKT8goGNWPmVbP0/K+MLSKEFjAkQKBgQD4Xgxk9LG/BtgYccBY\nDvXcnKLrZTPKFFg38pVhfgJw9HgEWgs9PGhFf1TrqCOFJfR4l64hsVCJJ+zTStlk\nxBZsPIGFcD/hDiRh+rneSTGJv4ODUcGqe/eGp/WwDSY+36fcDXj5RA/2yIVdTs4j\nH4J/JW6ZWUyhyd/8fRqed6bIcQKBgQDV1e1gbYpnahMRKrAN6H3wlBt6R3Mmc50C\nMnGn9O14YcIVm/1Xnwjse+koqt74aJCxFEcCPdMK1E0Tkd0lOvWYDmsqPFSgJzkO\nQt/EDkMe4UFh44idBwZGhbr2D/oIGqD4Ot6iUagfGviI1XQabKMet/WR3DglYpPV\nCsG6SQ8PGwKBgQCFXjtZmuw3n/06YxreLmpn5NS3gsikovgcUu9UQs4cyaoI7DFM\n2LtFVnLLeKZaQV9dwlWHUifk/sN1UqQaMBG6XWNPvE8REv8GfhSBANzREz4TrjtI\nyPjKHjcYKnd3G7KPv8xOTfYkltjGmiKnSaxRilAxmHpGBpl4g9VfcvDkgQKBgQDQ\nHa0yNGqHy81S3+EJKEWqZ/t2PyPrQIqHIOFNPiwBBeQHdBJVvQrKXq7GTcdErUBl\nl/6kR9emqol5inVZTtDIdQAH0z/pv0LghmWSQu9AlqszwmerrLKG4JDd+x611HTm\nIyWbhS3DWFSbmGOvdBwuQYxXsaVTfWWz6wwxafmmEQKBgE6bp3QC5Uu0H/M4t5FY\nQnpDf2im64BixaBoVCYMwip3IHfl1LaK+v9PnaxrwXFX+uOFMRvvfvA6oVvwTIJv\n2NbmCfx8aF8+wrFa4S+QkPfzXC9cQxAFC0Dd8jPlFg84v8R9PhnL3Ty6tTZXCAII\nr/kKDFm/VK3aUvpC92m5xfTE\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "translate@central-eon-267809.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "100927717394460781967",
  "auth_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
  "token_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/translate%40central-eon-267809.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

The error:

```
[02-Apr-2021 15:49:52 Europe/Brussels] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}
 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(69): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create()
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}()
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler()
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(248): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run()
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\vendor\guzzleh in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imzo.be\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113
```

Does anyone know what is wrong in this?
I think everything is configured correctly in the Google Cloud.
It might be a problem with the auth_uri or token_uri.
Please help.